# i want to take the last word and use end( ) function i get an error

Tags: php

```
$allowed=array('jpg','jpqg','gif','png','JPG','JPEG','GIF','PNG');

$file_name=$_FILES['profile']['name'];
$file_extn= end(explode('.',$file_name));
$file_temp=$_FILES['profile']['tmp_name'];

if(in_array($file_extn,$allowed) == true) {
    //change_profile_image($_SESSION['id'],$file_temp);
}
else {
    echo'incorrect file type .Allowed:';
    echo implode(', ',$allowed);
}
```

The error is:

> Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in

When I use end function get this error

Comment: I would check for the file mime-type aswell

Answer (score 2):

To get the file extension use like below:

```
$ext = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Answer (score 1):

The warning message says it all. You must store explode result in a variable before using `end`

for example:

```
$pieces = explode('.',$file_name);
$file_extn= end($pieces);
```

~ Edit:

The `end` function takes the argument as *reference*. It means the funcion uses the memory address instead of the value. Thats why we must store the return from `explode` in a variable.

You can read more about passing by reference in this link: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

And here is the `end` doc: http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php